# Structural equation model / Regression residuals and interactions

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I want to calculate a structural equation model (SEM).

There are 3 function-specific indicators: `IES_flex`, `IES_ic` and `d` that make up the latent variable Executive Functions `EF`. The variance of `EF` was fixed to one.

The goal was to evaluate the contribution of the `EF` and function-specific indicators to self-control, `BSCS`, measured/observed with a self-rating questionnaire,.

We also want to treat the residuals of `IES_flex`, `IES_ic`, and `d`, i.e., the variance, as predictors. Because we think the relationship between the four `EF` factors, `EF` and the three residuals, and self-control is moderated through two further variables, `AOF` and `AOP`, both measured/observed with a self-rating questionnaire,  these variables were integrated in the model. So the four `EF` factors, `AOF`, `AOP` interactions between the `EF`
factors and `AOF` and `AOP` were included as predictors in a SEM predicting self-control. We used the `lavaan` package.

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L), d = c(0.627550651847074, 0.627550651847074, 
-1.25488425977031, -2.196101715579, 1.15724880920241, 0.627550651847074, 
0.33421021229571, 0.745729510749062, 1.15724880920241, 1.15724880920241, 
-0.843364961316958, 0.627550651847074, -0.72518610241497, 0.0978524944917336, 
1.15724880920241, 0.33421021229571, 0.216031353393722, -0.0773090861576415, 
-1.43004584041969, -0.900347683064346, 0.745729510749062, -0.19548794505963, 
-2.196101715579, -1.25488425977031, 0.0978524944917336, -0.313666803961618, 
-0.607007243512982), IES_ic = c(0.903246908249129, 0.608280005625906, 
-0.651212978846396, 0.657310408322585, 1.21305673020249, -1.04692343679818, 
-0.903284598584151, 0.262713727419709, -0.626403780452018, -0.91538007206007, 
1.45121068878722, 0.841762347441691, -1.41934878331439, -0.299243983786715, 
1.21342325970176, -1.14073251937004, 0.459472079702781, -0.259362000494534, 
-1.49045737622129, 0.398822125305692, 1.26033903560836, -0.797724102794307, 
0.269976328580042, 0.889518395494059, 0.26777715158442, -0.738683217257273, 
-0.98266764803722), IES_flex = c(0.611376670202966, 0.100019803482406, 
-0.375879963693191, 0.832183290075242, 1.08417699970122, 0.901722484622191, 
-0.367500997199248, 0.726569152639851, 0.443174501563025, -1.9680067473553, 
1.0716305189065, 0.832203725126164, -0.0294727224025174, -1.09829525782315, 
0.672854247160833, -2.03419485699619, 0.178295825969132, -0.419626289631151, 
-1.34447496846711, 0.410673189009022, 0.608304448372783, 0.588371276471592, 
-0.277360713478181, -0.827612393483032, 1.31165502930096, -0.735856606954008, 
-1.42448433147589), AOP = c(1.02516676018312, 1.02516676018312, 
-1.04630421915597, 1.02516676018312, -0.0105687294864242, -0.0105687294864242, 
-0.0105687294864242, -0.528436474321195, 0.507299015348346, -1.04630421915597, 
-2.59990745366028, -0.528436474321195, 1.02516676018312, 0.507299015348346, 
1.02516676018312, 0.507299015348346, 1.02516676018312, -0.528436474321195, 
1.02516676018312, -0.0105687294864242, -1.04630421915597, 1.02516676018312, 
-1.04630421915597, 0.507299015348346, 0.507299015348346, 0.507299015348346, 
0.507299015348346), AOF = c(1.46940335759051, -1.18500270773428, 
2.13300487392171, 0.142200324928114, 0.474001083093712, -1.18500270773428, 
-0.189600433237485, 1.13760259942491, 0.474001083093712, 1.13760259942491, 
0.474001083093712, 1.13760259942491, -0.853201949568682, -0.853201949568682, 
0.474001083093712, -1.84860422406548, 1.13760259942491, -0.853201949568682, 
1.46940335759051, -1.84860422406548, 0.142200324928114, 0.142200324928114, 
-1.51680346589988, -1.51680346589988, -0.853201949568682, -0.521401191403083, 
0.142200324928114), BSCS = c(36, 47, 32, 53, 35, 34, 41, 19, 
40, 37, 27, 46, 37, 46, 50, 33, 41, 40, 49, 37, 35, 39, 50, 49, 
43, 40, 36)), .Names = c("id", "d", "IES_ic", "IES_flex", "AOP", 
"AOF", "BSCS"), row.names = c(NA, 27L), class = "data.frame")


HS.model <- '
# measurement model
EF  =~ IES_flex + IES_ic + d

a =~  EF*AOP
b =~  EF*AOF
c =~  EF*AOP*AOF

a_f =~  IES_flex*AOP
b_f =~  IEs_flex*AOF
c_f =~  IES_flex*AOP*AOF

a_i =~  IES_ic*AOP
b_i =~  IEs_ic*AOF
c_i =~  IES_ic*AOP*AOF

a_d =~  d*AOP
b_d =~  d*AOF
c_d =~  d*AOP*AOF

EF ~~ 1*EF
IES_flex ~~ IES_flex
IES_ic ~~ IES_ic
d ~~ d

# regression
BSCS ~ EF + AOF + AOP + IES_flex + IES_ic + d + a + b + c + a_f + b_f + c_f + a_i + b_i + c_i + a_d + b_d + c_d
'

fit <- sem(HS.model, data = ex,orthogonal = TRUE)

summary(fit,standardized=TRUE,fit.measures=T,rsquare=T)
parameterEstimates(fit,standardized=TRUE)
```

The error after fit <- sem(HS.model... was:

```
Error in lavaanify(model = FLAT, constraints = constraints, varTable = lavdata@ov,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: wrong number of arguments in modifier (EF,AOP) of element c=~AOF
```

My question is whether this is the right way to integrate the residuals and analyze the interactions?Should I do this analysis for each EF factor separately?

Comment: Hi, welcome to *Stack Overflow*, in order that we can help you best, please provide example data. Consider [*How to make a great reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038), thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I edit my first comment and provide example data. Thank you for helping